# Identifying Tomcat start up Programmatically

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a automation tool where I have to manage tomcat through java.
I can start and stop the tomcat using

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:/program files/tomcat/bin/startup.bat");` and

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:/program files/tomcat/bin/shutdown.bat");`

and I can deploy the war files by copying to the web apps folder on startup of tomcat.

The Issue is how to identify the tomcat is started programmatically .so that once it is started I can copy files into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Embedded Tomcat in your application. Have a look at this tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

The main entry point for Embedded Tomcat is this class:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html

Comment: This is really a much better way to do it than spawning a batch file to start Tomcat, unless you are writing a tool to manage a Tomcat instance installed on the system.  You _can_ copy the files before starting Tomcat, though...

Comment: By the way, if you want to manage Tomcat instance, you can write a simple wrapper that holds an Embedded Tomcat, and allows to control it via remote method calling, for instance - via RMI.